# Использование Strategy Pattern в случае, если конкретные стратегии зависят от типа использующего их объекта

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, проектирование, шаблон-стратегия

Пытаюсь спроектировать систему оружия для игры, в которой бы каждое оружие задавалось некоторой базой и несколькими переменными поведения. Примерно так:

```
public interface iWeapon {
    void Use();
}

public interface iReloadable {
    void Reload();
}

public interface iWeaponUseStrategy {
    void Perform();
}

public interface iWeaponReloadStrategy {
    void Perform();
}

public class BaseWeapon: iWeapon, iReloadable {

    public iWeaponUseStrategy UseStrategy;
    public iWeaponReloadStrategy ReloadStrategy;

    public void Use() {
         UseStrategy.Perform();
    }

    public void Reload() {
        ReloadStrategy.Perform();
    }
}
```

Когда появляется класс оружия, стратегии для которого зависят от состояния самого оружия начинаются трудности с адаптацией более общих стратегий для этого оружия. Текущая реализация выглядит так:

```
public interface iWeaponWithAmmoUseStrategy {
    // Теперь стратегия меняет состояние внешнего по отношению к ней объекта
    void Perform(WeaponWithAmmo weapon); 
}

public class SimpleAmmoUseStrategy : iWeaponWithAmmoUseStrategy {

    public void Perform(WeaponWithAmmo weapon) {
        // Изменение состояния внешнего объекта
        weapon.AmmoCurrent -= 1;
        // код выстрела
    }
}

...

public class WeaponWithAmmo: iWeapon, iReloadable {
    public int AmmoMax {get; set;}
    public int AmmoCurrent {get; set;}

    public iWeaponWithAmmoUseStrategy UseStrategy;

    public void Use() {
        UseStrategy.Perform(this);
    }

    ...
}
```

Мне не нравится то, что невозможно использовать существующие стратегии для `BaseWeapon` в новом `WeaponWithAmmo`. По логике стратегии `iWeaponUseStrategy` не имеют никаких специальных требований для оружия, в котором они применимы. А стратегии `iWeaponWithAmmoUseStrategy` "требуют" от оружия быть экземпляром класса `WeaponWithAmmo` или его подтипа. Тем не менее, первые не могут быть использованы в оружии `WeaponWithAmmo`.

Единственное решение, которое приходит в голову, это вынести зависимость от оружия в отдельный интерфейс, и для каждого нового класса оружия (и соответствующих ему стратегий) менять интерфейс `iWeaponUseStrategy`:

```
// Теперь перед использованием оружие надо инициализировать его стратегии
public iWeaponWithAmmoInit {
    void Init(WeaponWithAmmo weapon);
}

// Но затем можно вызывать методы стратегий без ссылки на внешний объект
public iWeaponWithAmmoUseStrategy {
    void Perform();
}

// Кроме того, нужно чтобы базовая стратегия являлась подтипом специфичных для оружия стратегий
// Меняем этот код каждый раз при добавлении класса оружия
public iWeaponUseStrategy : iWeaponWithAmmoUseStrategy, iSomeNewWeaponTypeUseStrategy {
    new void Perform();
}
```

Это очень некрасивое решение, нарушающее к тому же принцип "Существующий код должен быть закрыт для изменений".

Мне кажется, что изначально мои мысли пошли по неправильному пути и надо строить архитектуру как-то по-другому. Подскажите, в каком направлении лучше двигаться?

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь сложную систему правил закодировать в терминах иерархии объектов. Иерархии объектов просто не предназначены для этого.

Хуже того, ваша логика правил использования оружия оказывается размазанной по всем иерархии наследования.

Подобную проблему недавно обсуждал Эрик Липперт в цикле статей *Wizards and warriors*: [[1]](http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/), [[2]](http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/30/wizards-and-warriors-part-two/), [[3]](http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/04/wizards-and-warriors-part-three/), [[4]](http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/07/wizards-and-warriors-part-four/), [[5]](http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/11/wizards-and-warriors-part-five/). (Вы можете просмотреть сразу выводы в 5-ой статье или прочитать всю промежуточную логику с начала цикла.)

Присоединюсь к идее этих статей: просто создайте отдельную сущность «набор правил», в которой закодируйте все правила.

Comment: Спасибо за прекрасные статьи - открыл для себя новый подход к проектированию систем. 

И кроме того, в процессе прочтения осознал, что при постановке вопроса совершенно упустил из виду конечную задачу, которую необходимо решить - "гарантировать корректность инициализации системы геймдизайнерами" (например, невозможность установки режима огня "лазер" на оружие без "аккумулятора") и при такой постановке задачи использование отдельных сущностей "правила" и "команды" кажется вполне естественным.

Однако хотелось бы узнать какие еще подходы могут быть применимы в подобных ситуациях.

Comment: @AlexeyChernyh: Я описал всё, что знаю по этой теме — давайте подождём ответов от других участников. Может быть, коллективный разум подскажет ещё что-то.